# How can I shrink an LVM partition on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

I'm trying to reduce the size of a partition on a CentOS 5.8 VM as my predecessor allocated far too much space to it. However, I've tried a variety of different methods and have run into problems with all of them. The details of the current partitions is below:

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number   Start   End    Size   Type      File system   Flags
1        32.3kB  107MB  107MB  primary   ext3          boot
2        107MB   215GB  215GB  primary                 lvm
```

When I try to resize the partition using Parted (running off of a Knoppix Live-CD with the system partition unmounted) I get this error:

```
(parted) resize 2 107 30827

WARNING: you are attempting to use parted to operate on (resize) a file system. parted's file system manipulation code is not as robust as what you'll find in dedicated, file-system-specific packages like e2fsprogs. We recommend you use parted only to manipulate partition tables, whenever possible. Support for performing most operations on most types of file systems will be removed in an upcoming release.
Error: Could not detect file system.
```

I've tried to find a good guide on how to do this with e2fsprogs but everything I've come across isn't explaining how to resize the lvm partition like I need to.

I'm new to the Linux world so perhaps this is basic and I'm overanalyzing but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Growing file system is easy. Shrinking the file system is trickier and not supported by all file systems. ext3 and ext4 do support shrinking, though, but **BE VERY CAREFUL WITH IT**. Make absolutely sure you have good backups. Then, verify once more you have good backups.

You should first shrink the file system itself with `resize2fs /dev/yourdevice newsizegoeshere`.

Next you need to shrink the logical volume: `lvresize -L X /path/to/your/logical_volume`, where `X` is the new size expressed in some way. I purposely left out the syntax, see `man lvresize` for available options to see your preferred way to tell the new size. You can subtract from the old size or just specify the new size.

<strike>Next you need to shrink the volume group itself with `vgresize`, if you see that necessary. Alternatively you can just create new logical volumes inside the volume group, now that the previous step with lvresize gave you some space to breathe.</strike>

If you took the `vgresize` route, you finally need to adjust the partition size with `fdisk` by deleting the partition, and recreating it with the exactly same starting block as before and making the size smaller than before.

**EDIT**: It appears that with LVM2 volume group shrinking is not that trivial thing to do. You may need to delete the volume group and recreate it... oh dear. So, how about my footnote, would it work?

If you and/or software fail in any of these steps, your data goes boof. So once more: **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE GOOD BACKUPS**.

---

Oh, and as your copy-paste mentions VMware: could you just create a new virtual disk in VMware, copy over your stuff from your over-sized disk to the new disk, nuke the over-sized disk from the orbit and call it a day?

Comment: `vgresize` is not something I'm familiar with. Could it be `vgreduce` ? But even that only manages the number of LVs in a VG.

Comment: @Tommy: Weird, I'm sure I've seen it somewhere! Now that I took a look, no such thing. Gotta check.

Comment: @Tommy: OK, this should tell how often I've actually reduced the volume group sizes. It seems that vgresize was part of the original LVM, not LVM2! :-) Usually I only need vgextend, anyway.

Comment: Fortunately this is a VM so I created a snapshot of the system that I can revert to if I mess anything seriously up. Thanks for this, I'm going to run through it and will let you know if I run into any issues.

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin: I just edited my post a bit.

Comment: How can I find the path to my logical volume? I ran "mount" but this doesn't appear to show the logical volume I'm looking for since I'm booted into a Knoppix Live-CD.

Comment: Run `vgscan && vgchange -a y` so the volumes will be found. I hope ;)

Comment: They were found. Using lvdisplay to find the path.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. These TRULY sounds like famous last words. "Fortunately this is a VM so I created a snapshot of the system that I can revert to if I mess anything seriously up. "

Comment: Alright. Well I was just hoping to teach myself how to do something new rather than blowing the system away and rebuilding. However, perhaps that is my best bet at this point. It will require a good bit more time but it is probably the safer bet at this point in time.

Comment: Take the safe route if you have anything at all worth storing there. It's always the best way, even if it initially takes more time. Screwing something up is the actual time vampire; recovering from scratch can be painful, even more so if there's a problem with backups...

Comment: Thanks for your help in any case. I'm confident in my backups but I might as well take the time to rebuild a proper system as you said. Cheers.